# reactjs - axios post call

Tags: reactjs, axios

I am trying to do an axios post call and getting en error like below. I have tried all routes available in blogs, still getting the same error.  Pls suggest.

```
var headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}
const dt = JSON.stringify({"name": "ddd"});
return axios.post('https://exam.com/apps', dt, headers)
    .then(function(response) {
        console.log("xxx", response.data["name"])
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.log("axios error:",error)
    });
```

Error msg:

```
xhr.js:178 POST https://exam.com/apps 400 (Bad Request)
axios error: Error: Request failed with status code 400
at createError (createError.js:16)
at settle (settle.js:18)
at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:77)
```

Comment: http 400 status code may be correct response of REST api in a case if you provide invalid information for API call. Check if your request (number and types of arguments, you're passing to server) is correct.

Comment: yes, i tried the same data thru postman with POST call, it is giving me 201 created response

Comment: try this: `axios.post('https://exam.com/apps', dt, {headers})` 3rd arg should be an object, that contains the customs headers.

Comment: yes, i tried the same.  getting 403 forbidden error with `Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 403`

Comment: are you using react with redux ?

Comment: No Aaqib, I am not using redux.  Trying a simple axios post call on button click.

Comment: It doesn't matter what you use. The problem is with your request. Try this: 
`return axios.post('https://exam.com/apps', dt, {
     headers: your_header_params
})`

Comment: yes Michael, tried the same `{ headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json' } }`.  Again getting same error 403 forbidden `Response for preflight has invalid HTTP`

Answer (score 0):

```
 var authOptions = {
   method: 'post',
   url: 'https://exam.com/apps',
   data: JSON.stringify({"name": "ddd"});,
   headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
   },
   json: true
  };
  axios(authOptions)
     .then((response) => {
         console.log(response);
          })
     .catch((error) => {
          alert(error)
        })
```